# customize JSON using JAVASCRIPT before post in PHP file to UPDATE Mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

*I m posting JSON data to a php file by using javascript*

---

POST:

```
{
 "serial[1]":"25252",
 "serial[1][1]":["552","7","9","5252525","20","2"],
 "serial[1][2]":["5225","11","33","52525525255252","200","1"],
 "serial[1][3]":["5252","5","137","htyjjyt","100","3"]
 "serial[2]":"532573",
 "serial[2][1]":["052","7","9","525252","50","1"],
 "serial[2][2]":["5005","4","152","50505","300","1"],
 "serial[2][3]":["505050","5","137","5050","300","1"],
 "serial[2][4]":["5055","11","33","50505","20","1"]
 }
```

---

I would like this kind of structure

```
{
"serial[1]":
   [
    "serial[1][1]":["25252","552","7","9","5252525","20","2"],
    "serial[1][2]":["25252","5225","11","33","525252","200","1"],
    "serial[1][3]":["25252","5252","5","137","htyjjyt","100","3"]
   ]
"serial[2]":
   [
     "serial[2][1]":["532573","052","7","9","525252","50","1"],
     "serial[2][2]":["532573","4","152","50505","300","1"],
     "serial[2][3]":["532573","5","137","5050","300","1"],
     "serial[2][4]":["532573","11","33","50505","20","1"]
  ]
```

}

---

I am using this function to post the data

```
$('#inForm').click(function() {
var data = JSON.stringify($('#inForm').serializeObject());

$.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url: '../php/device_final_register.php', 
    data:{data:data}, 
    cache:false, 
    success: function(result) {

       $('#completeModal .modal-body').html(result);
      }
   });
}
```

---

I have 2 problems:

i.e serial[1][2] means [serial number 1] and [channel number 2]

1. What's the best way to post the data in a good JSON structure
2. How to save the data to a Mysql database by using a loop from this JSON

---

**Datas comes from this table** for each SERIAL

```
  <table class="col-lg-12" id="slave[1]>
     // table 1 content
  </table>

  <table class="col-lg-12" id="slave[2]>
   <div>
    <input class="form-control col-lg-1"  name="serial[2]" id="serial[2]" value="14242" disabled />
   </div>
  <thead>
     <tr>
           <th class="col-lg-1">Channel</th>
           <th class="col-lg-1">Disj.</th>
           <th class="col-lg-2">Category</th> 
           <th class="col-lg-2">Appliance</th>
           <th class="col-lg-3">Description</th>
           <th class="col-lg-1">CT type</th>
           <th class="col-lg-1">Phase</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
          <td><input class="form-control col-lg-1" name="serial[2][1]" id="disj[2][1]"/></td>
        <td>
           <div class="category">
                <select class="form-control" id="cat[2][1]" name="serial[2][1]" >
              // options  
                </select>
           </div>
         </td>
        <td>
          <div class="appliance" id="app21">
                <select class="form-control" id="cat[2][1]" name="appl[2][1]" >
              // options  
         </select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input class="form-control col-lg-3" name="serial[2][1]" id="desc[2][1]"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control col-lg-1"  name="serial[2][1]" id="CT[2][1]">
             // options 
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control col-lg-1" name="serial[2][1]" id="phase[2][1]">
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       // Same for others (name="serial[2][2]" id="disj[2][2]" .....)
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Show where the data comes from.

Comment: Is ***52525525255252*** in the dataset `"serial[1][2]":["5225","11","33","52525525255252","200","1"]` a typo? It looks different in your original dataset vs the desired dataset. I'm wondering if this is a typo and that you only want the structure to change or if you want the structure to change and the data to be manipulated too?

Comment: I'd suggest u to break the serialize concept to individual table so as to form separate array array1 and array2 and then join or merge them to form output as you desired..